# This code is working fine if ($(this).val() == "Spine") but not ($(this).val() == "Spine"||"Brian")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is working fine if `($(this).val() == "Spine")` but if `($(this).val() == "Spine"||"Brian")` then the selection menu closes then opens again when the selection for `"optionbodyRegion" == ""` What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#optionbodyRegion").change(function(){

                if ($(this).val() == "Spine"||"Brain") {

                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[0]=new Option("Select", "", false, false)
                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[1]=new Option("With", "With", false, false)
                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[2]=new Option("Without", "Without", false, false)
                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[3]=new Option("With and Without", "With and Without", false, false)


                    $("#contrast").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect

                } else {
                    if ($(this).val() == "" ) {
                    $("#contrast").slideUp("fast");   //Slide Up Effect

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Although it feels natural to say, in English, `if x equals a or b` in most programming languages you need to be explicit and say `if x equals a or x equals b`

Comment: Feel free to accept any of these answers as it will increase your reputation as well as the user who took the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 13):

You have wrong syntax in using the logical or `||` operator

Change

```
 if ($(this).val() == "Spine"||"Brain") {
```

To

```
if ($(this).val() == "Spine"|| $(this).val() == "Brain") {
```

You can use value with javascript object instead of val() of jquery object, as Fabrício Matté suggested. It would give you performance benefit.

```
if (this.value == "Spine" || this.value == "Brain")
```

Comment: Or `if (this.value == "Spine" || this.value == "Brain")` for the sake of the milliseconds and simplicity.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the benefits of jQuery, but why folks reach for it to do the simplest of built-in operations is beyond me..

Answer (score 4):

You must state a complete condition /test on each side of the 'OR'.

```
if($(this).val() == "Spine" || $(this).val() == "Brain")
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
  if (($(this).val() == "Spine")||($(this).val() =="Brain")))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is:

```
if ($(this).val() == "Spine"|| $(this).val() == "Brain")
```

As is, you code has an error regarding Operator Precedence. I'd recommend looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Your version will always return true, as any non-zero length string will resolve to true when used in a boolean context. There are many articles on Javascript's quirky behaviour when it comes to boolean evaluations. A basic outline of some of some of the most common ones can be found at http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approach.  Especially if the list grows. If you get a list that has several parts, the conditional gets ugly.

```
var parts = ["Spine", "Brain"];
var value = $(this).val();

if($.inArray(value, parts) > -1){
    //do something    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

or use switch case

```
$("#optionbodyRegion").change(function(){
    switch ($(this).val())
{
   case "Spine": case "Brain": 
    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[0]=new Option("Select", "", false, false)
                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[1]=new Option("With", "With", false, false)
                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[2]=new Option("Without", "Without", false, false)
                    document.getElementById('optioncontrast').options[3]=new Option("With and Without", "With and Without", false, false)


                    $("#contrast").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
   break;
 case "":
$("#contrast").slideUp("fast");   //Slide Up Effect
break;

  default: 
  break;
}
```